# php glob() not returning all files

Tags: php, image, glob

I searched this site and found a very useful snippet of code that i've  been able to use.

```
  $counter = 0; 
     foreach (glob("images/gallery/photo_gallery/resized/*.jpg") as $pathToThumb)
    {
        $filename = basename($pathToThumb);
        $pathToLarge = 'images/gallery/photo_gallery/' . $filename;
        echo ('<a href="'.$pathToLarge.'"><img src="'.$pathToThumb.'" /></a>');
        $counter++;
    }
```

But for some reason this will only return the first 30 images in my directory. (there are 81) Can anyone think why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: show us the result and the result you're expecting

Comment: Can you show some example file names? Are you 10000% sure they end in `jpg` and not, for example, `jpeg`? Are you sure it's not a rights issue? Also (not pertinent to the issue I think), in the web link you are creating, you are missing the `/resized` part.

Comment: What does this $counter variable do? And yes, there could be case sensitive names. Why not to just list all files, `"images/gallery/photo_gallery/resized/*"`? Wouldn't there any files, other than thumbnails?

Comment: the $counter variable was just for my use so I didn't have to count each result manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have said above

```
$path = 'images/gallery/photo_gallery/resized/*';
```

would be enough. or, if you stubbornly wants only jpg only,

```
$path = 'images/gallery/photo_gallery/resized/*.[Jj][Pg][Gg]';
```

as manual suggests

Comment: $path = 'images/gallery/photo_gallery/resized/*.[Jj][Pg][Gg]';

this does the trick for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone for input.

Here's the answer - file extensions are CASE-SENSITIVE when used in glob() (something I was un-aware of)

30 of my files end in .jpg whilst the remaining files have been auto renamed through a resizing program to .JPG

So this means `glob("imagesPath/*.jpg")` only returned the lower-case matches.

Another lesson learnt :)

Hopefully this answer can help someone else too. :)